# How to get QuickBlox token in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, token, quickblox, hmacsha1

Have to use Quickblox's RESTful API instead of their iOS SDK due to work restrictions, and having trouble generating a valid signature according to [their tutorial](http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#Signature_generation).

Below is the response I get from my call:

```
2014-07-25 16:19:12.646 test[2247:60b]response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x10c41ae40> { URL:https://api.quickblox.com/session.json } { status code: 422, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Fri, 25 Jul 2014 23:19:12 GMT";
"QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
Server = "nginx/1.0.15";
Status = "422 Unprocessable Entity";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
"X-Request-Id" = 8413fb7182cee06857619b14f363ed78;
"X-Runtime" = "0.004821";
"X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
} } data: {"errors":{"base":["Unexpected signature"]}} connectionError: (null)
```

And below is the method I'm using make the call:

```
- (void) retrieveQBTokenTest{

// Authentication data
NSString *appId = @"12345";
NSString *authKey = @"ypqdqEx7sOeWEQr";
NSString *timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
NSString *nonce = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (arc4random()%1000)+1];
NSString *authSecret = @"dtoA5bkNrBUZn5L";
NSString *dataStringForSig = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application_id=%@&auth_key=%@&nonce=%@&timestamp=%@", appId, authKey, nonce, timestamp];
NSString *sig = [self hmacsha1:dataStringForSig secret:authSecret];

// Package authentication data into JSON
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                       @"application_id":appId,
                       @"auth_key":authKey,
                       @"timestamp":timestamp,
                       @"nonce":nonce,
                       @"signature":sig
                       };
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
NSLog(@"%s: jsonString: %@", __FUNCTION__, [[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

// Generate request
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.quickblox.com/session.json"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    // Headers
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"0.1.1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"QuickBlox-REST-API-Version"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]];
    [request setValue:length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    // Body
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

// Make call
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    NSString *dataResponseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%s: response: %@ data: %@ connectionError: %@", __FUNCTION__, response, dataResponseString, connectionError);
}];
}
```

And finally, my hashing method:

```
- (NSString *)hmacsha1:(NSString *)data secret:(NSString *)key {

const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
NSString *hash = [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

return hash;
}
```

Looks like the way I'm generating the signature is no good, but not sure where I'm messing up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proper signature generation method:

```
+ (NSString *)signData:(NSData *)data withSecret:(NSString *)secret{
    NSData *secretData = [secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *clearTextData = data;
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};
    CCHmacContext hmacContext;
    CCHmacInit(&hmacContext, kCCHmacAlgSHA1, secretData.bytes, secretData.length);
    CCHmacUpdate(&hmacContext, clearTextData.bytes, clearTextData.length);
    CCHmacFinal(&hmacContext, digest);
    NSData *result = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    NSString *hash = [result description];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];

    return hash;
}
```

And usage:

```
[SignHelper signData:[self rawBodyWithoutEncode] withSecret:[QBSettings authorizationSecret]]


- (NSData *)rawBodyWithoutEncode
{
    NSData *raw = nil;

    NSMutableString *params = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    // sort
    NSMutableArray *sortKeys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[parameters allKeys]];
    [sortKeys sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    for (id s in sortKeys){
        [params appendFormat:@"%@=%@&", s, [parameters objectForKey:s]];
    }
    [params deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([params length] - 1, 1)];

    raw = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return raw;
}
```

...

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary 
                               dictionary];
NSUInteger appID = [QBSettings applicationID];
NSString *authKey = [QBSettings authorizationKey];
NSUInteger nonce = arc4random()%1000;
NSUInteger timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

[params setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)appID] forKey:@"application_id"];
[params setValue:authKey forKey:@"auth_key"];
[params setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)nonce] forKey:@"nonce"];
[params setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)timestamp] forKey:@"timestamp"];
```