# How to get and use QuickBlox token in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, token, quickblox

Have to use Quickblox's RESTful API partly instead of their iOS SDK due to work restrictions.Must be login without knowledge of password of QuickBlox user. For mobile application exists server version too. In iOS QuickBlox SDK i see only for facebook or twitter and no custom https://sdk.quickblox.com/ios/documentation/sdk/Categories/QBRequest+QBAuth.html#//api/name/logInWithSocialProvider:accessToken:accessTokenSecret:successBlock:errorBlock: .

Is it possible login to QuickBlox without an knowledge of password ?

I add user[login] (in this parameter i have e-mail) to parameters and do request as in first post of this article [How to get QuickBlox token in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965971/how-to-get-quickblox-token-in-objective-c). In QuickBlox SDK i did not found giving token.

According to documentation give the success response from server with states 201 - it gives me too. But user_id = 0.
It would be created session and i get token. I edited ”application_id”:XXXXX to XXXXX, server gives me the real data.
Next actions for checking token is good or no - login by 2 methods - the gives not authorised 401 response.

How i can use token in next my needs ?

Why gives user_id = 0 ?

What i do wrong ?

May be the mixed method using REST and QuickBlox iOS SDK together, for example create the session or logIn by token, and set this session to iOS SDK libraries - QMChatViewController, QMServices, Quickblox-WebRTC ?

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary
                                   dictionary];

[parameters setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)appID] forKey:@"application_id"];
[parameters setValue:authKey forKey:@"auth_key"];
[parameters setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)nonce] forKey:@"nonce"];
[parameters setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)timestamp] forKey:@"timestamp"];
[parameters setValue:email forKey:@"user[login]"];

NSString *sig = [self  signData:[self rawBodyWithoutEncode:parameters] withSecret:sekret];
// Package authentication data into JSON
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                       @"application_id":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)appID],
                       @"auth_key":authKey,
                       @"nonce":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)nonce],
                       @"timestamp":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)timestamp],
                       @"signature":sig,
                       @"user[login]":email,

                       };
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
NSLog(@"%s: jsonString: %@", __FUNCTION__, [[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

// Generate request
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.quickblox.com/session.json"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
// Headers
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"0.1.1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"QuickBlox-REST-API-Version"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]];
[request setValue:length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// Body
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

// Make call
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    NSString *dataResponseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%s: response: %@ data: %@ connectionError: %@", __FUNCTION__, response, dataResponseString, connectionError);

    NSString *password =  [QBSession currentSession].sessionDetails.token;
    NSLog(@"password = %@",password);
//        NSString *password1 = [QBBaseModule sharedModule].token;
    [QBRequest logInWithUserLogin:email password:password successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
        NSLog(@"logInWithUserLogin response = %@, user = %@",response, user);
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        NSLog(@"logInWithUserLogin error response = %@",response);
    }];
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];
    [QBRequest logInWithUserLogin:email password:[[json objectForKey:@"session"] objectForKey:@"token"] successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
        NSLog(@"2 logInWithUserLogin response = %@, user = %@",response, user);
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        NSLog(@"2 logInWithUserLogin error response = %@",response);
    }];
}];
```

And it log from server

```
    response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x16e68e70> { URL: https://api.quickblox.com/session.json } { status code: 201, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 257;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Sat, 04 Jun 2016 12:32:20 GMT";
Etag = "\"3d96a2460db32532039e9affe08a6320\"";
"QB-Token-ExpirationDate" = "2016-06-04 14:32:20 UTC";
"QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
Server = "nginx/1.8.1";
Status = "201 Created";
"Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=15768000;";
"X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
"X-Request-Id" = 192027ebe9d9c17c32af5827b419b800;
"X-Runtime" = "0.014884";
"X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
} } data: {"session":"_id":"5752ca54a28f9ac35900000c","application_id”:XXXXX,”created_at":"2016-06-04T12:32:20Z","device_id":0,"nonce":866,"token":"62a6d1f1c12fd52561d9f86f2599666756bdbf8f","ts":1465043526,"updated_at":"2016-06-04T12:32:20Z","user_id":0,"id":22817}} connectionError: (null)
2016-06-04 15:32:20.395 test[3295:1366011] password = 9967a14ffbef25355042d4b7b3896a95349b5227
[QBCore] Response error reasons: {
errors =     (
    Unauthorized
);
}
[QBCore] Response error reasons: {
errors =     (
    Unauthorized
);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use QuickBlox iOS SDK http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS ?

Comment: I added in start of post the answer to question of Igor Khomenko.